# Tabbed feeds with ajax vs. without on homepage

Tags: ajax, seo, performance

I have a tabbed section on my homepage where I call different feeds for new posts by category of my site much like the new youtube layout. I have 10 different feeds so my question is how important is to have those feeds crawled because I'd like to just rotate them with ajax rather than have all of it called and hidden on page load. I looked into the hash tag solution for crawling ajax but that doesn't seem to apply in this situation where the only thing needing crawled is the homepage. The other question is if I let it all load hidden without ajax is that going to dramatically slow down load times or is not so bad because the content isn't actually being shown on load?

Comment: This is really not a WordPress question. Ask SEO questions on webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with jQuery UI tabs where the feeds would be hidden because WordPress caches feeds for 12 hours using the [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API).

This would be less expensive than doing an Ajax call for each tab.

Use  [`fetch_feed`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed) to parse and and cache.

The cache times can be filtered using [`wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime`](http://wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime).